# jQuery dialog open causes page to continuously lengthen in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, jquery

I made my first dialog and AJAX work in jQuery and finally got everything working great - the dialog has a few buttons, cancel, save, and generate to get a new random string from the server.  The problem is when I make the dialog modal (graying out the rest of the window), then in IE the scrollbars appear and sometimes keep moving as the page continuously extends down.  This happens whenever the dialog is opened (it's not initially set to open) but not everytime.  I can't think of any part of my code that would do this as I don't even have a JS loop anywhere.  Googling for this didn't help.  It seems like an IE vs jQuery quirk but any ideas?

Edit>
Thanks for the responses.
Ok here is some code!  This is my working demo which does the same thing and is pretty much the jquery UI modal dialog example at http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-form , only I couldn't get IE to act that way on that jquerui.com example.  Actually I went over it and it's the same darn code, even the "destroy".  What's the difference?

```
<style type="text/css">
    body { font-size: 62.5%; padding: 10px 50px;}
    label, input { display:block; }
    input.text { margin-bottom:12px; width:95%; padding: .4em; }
    fieldset { padding:0; border:0; margin-top:25px; }
    h1 { font-size: 1.2em; margin: .6em 0; }
    div#users-contain { width: 350px; margin: 20px 0; }
    div#users-contain table { margin: 1em 0; border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%; }
    div#users-contain table td, div#users-contain table th { border: 1px solid #eee; padding: .6em 10px; text-align: left; }
    .ui-dialog .ui-state-error { padding: .3em; }
    .validateTips { border: 1px solid transparent; padding: 0.3em; }
</style>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
        // a workaround for a flaw in the demo system (http://dev.jqueryui.com/ticket/4375), ignore!
        $( "#dialog:ui-dialog" ).dialog( "destroy" );

        var name = $( "#name" ),
                email = $( "#email" ),
                password = $( "#password" ),
                allFields = $( [] ).add( name ).add( email ).add( password ),
                tips = $( ".validateTips" );

        function updateTips( t ) {
                tips
                        .text( t )
                        .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" );
                setTimeout(function() {
                        tips.removeClass( "ui-state-highlight", 1500 );
                }, 500 );
        }

        function checkLength( o, n, min, max ) {
                if ( o.val().length > max || o.val().length < min ) {
                        o.addClass( "ui-state-error" );
                        updateTips( "Length of " + n + " must be between " +
                                min + " and " + max + "." );
                        return false;
                } else {
                        return true;
                }
        }

        function checkRegexp( o, regexp, n ) {
                if ( !( regexp.test( o.val() ) ) ) {
                        o.addClass( "ui-state-error" );
                        updateTips( n );
                        return false;
                } else {
                        return true;
                }
        }

        $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                height: 300,
                width: 350,
                modal: true,
                buttons: {
                        "Create an account": function() {
                                var bValid = true;
                                allFields.removeClass( "ui-state-error" );

                                bValid = bValid && checkLength( name, "username", 3, 16 );
                                bValid = bValid && checkLength( email, "email", 6, 80 );
                                bValid = bValid && checkLength( password, "password", 5, 16 );

                                bValid = bValid && checkRegexp( name, /^[a-z]([0-9a-z_])+$/i, "Username may consist of a-z, 0-9, underscores, begin with a letter." );
                                // From jquery.validate.js (by joern), contributed by Scott Gonzalez: http://projects.scottsplayground.com/email_address_validation/
                                bValid = bValid && checkRegexp( email, /^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$/i, "eg. ui@jquery.com" );
                                bValid = bValid && checkRegexp( password, /^([0-9a-zA-Z])+$/, "Password field only allow : a-z 0-9" );

                                if ( bValid ) {
                                        $( "#users tbody" ).append( "<tr>" +
                                                "<td>" + name.val() + "</td>" +
                                                "<td>" + email.val() + "</td>" +
                                                "<td>" + password.val() + "</td>" +
                                        "</tr>" );
                                        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                                }
                        },
                        Cancel: function() {
                                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                        }
                },
                close: function() {
                        allFields.val( "" ).removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
                }
        });

        $( "#create-user" )
                .button()
                .click(function() {
                        $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog( "open" );
                });
});
</script>
```

```
<div class="demo">

    <div id="dialog-form" title="Create new user">
        <p class="validateTips">All form fields are required.</p>

        <form method="post" id="new_user_form" name="new_user_form" action="">
        <fieldset>
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
        </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>


    <div id="users-contain" class="ui-widget">
        <h1>Existing Users:</h1>
        <table id="users" class="ui-widget ui-widget-content">
            <thead>
                <tr class="ui-widget-header ">
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>Password</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>John Doe</td>
                    <td>john.doe@example.com</td>
                    <td>johndoe1</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <button id="create-user">Create new user</button>

</div><!-- End demo -->
```

Comment: We need code!  jsfiddle a working example.

Comment: The scrollbars' display is probably unrelated to the problem at hand but I always call `$('body').css('overflow','hidden');` when opening a modal dialog and then `$('body').css('overflow','auto');` to reset when done - looks much better that way.

Answer (score 1):

Ah I had been using jQuery UI 1.9m2 (milestone 2 release) and the current official release is 1.8.10.  I downloaded and tried the other one and it no longer did that.  I guess I'm off to report a bug with the in-development version.  I need 1.9 for the tooltips.

Answer (score 0):

Well, i always resolve that by "hacking" the jQuery UI css.
Something like this:

```
.ui-widget-overlay { position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%!important; height: 100%!important; }
```